# React native firebase realtime database reference return null

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use realtime database, but reference is returning null. Not working on ios and android.

```
database().ref('/users/123')
// returns "null/users/123"
```

If I do it like this, then it works. But you should not need to put the url of the database. It should find the default database ref.

```
const database = firebase.app().database(URL);

const reference = database.ref('/user/123');
// returns "URL/user/123"
```

Database location: Belgium (europe-west1)

"@react-native-firebase/app": "12.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/database": "12.8.0",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For databases outside of the US (the original region) it is now recommended to specify the URL in code, instead of depending on it being read from the config file.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start):

> To get a reference to a database other than a `us-central1` default database, you must pass the database URL to `getInstance()` (or Kotlin+KTX `database()`) . For a `us-central1` default database, you can call `getInstance()` (or database) without arguments.